# Error with Numerical Integration

Tags: graphics, numerical-integration

I'm running the following code:

```
G = 0.01;
ωc = 15;
β = 1;
ω0 = 11;
integral1[t_, ω_?NumericQ] = 
G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] Sinc[(ω - 1) t/2]^2;

Plot[1 - 2 t^2 NIntegrate[
integral1[t, ω], {ω, 0, Infinity}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15], {t, 0, 100}]
```

But i get the errors:

[image]

What could be causing the errors? I have used the _?NumericQ command and I think the syntax is correct too.

Comment: Clear all your variables and try again. If need be, start in a fresh session.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Remove["Global`*"]

G = 1/100;
ωc = 15;

f[t_ , ω_] := G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] (Sin[(ω - 1) t/2]/((ω - 1) t/2))^2

Int[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[t , ω], {ω, 0, Infinity}]

Plot[1 - 2*t^2*Int[t], {t, 10^-15, 100}]
```

[image]

MMA has problems with function `Sinc` give some error messages:

```
f[t_ , ω_] := G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] (Sinc[(ω - 1) t/2])^2

Int2[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[t , ω], {ω, 0, Infinity}]

Int2[1]
```

[image]
that so I changed to `Sinc[x] -> Sin[x]/x`,but gives correct result.